# 'pgfmathresult' uses the argument for 'text opacity'

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency

I'm working on a figure of a graph with nodes. I put a white transparent box behind the node label using `fill=white` and `opacity=0.8` and then I tried using `text opacity=1.0` so that the text is still readable. The problem is that the node labels, created in a for-loop, end up having `1.0` instead of the correct number. The graph I get and the graph I want are pictured below:

[image: Incorrect graph]
[image: Correct graph]

I haven't found any posts relating `text opacity` to `pgfmathresult`. Here is a MWE of the code I have:

```
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [
          every label/.style={inner sep=0pt, opacity=0.8, text opacity=1.0, fill=white},
          cnode/.style={draw=black,fill=#1,minimum width=3mm,circle},
        ]
        \node[cnode=red,label=0:{$\hat y_1$}] (s1) at (6,-1) {};
        \node[cnode=red,label=0:{$\hat y_2$}] (s2) at (6,-2) {};
        \node at (6,-3) {$\vdots$};
        \node[cnode=red,label=0:{$\hat y_K$}] (sK) at (6,-4) {};

        \foreach \x in {0,...,4}
        {   
            \pgfmathparse{\x<4 ? \x : "q-1"}
            \ifthenelse{\x>0}
            {
                \node[cnode=gray,label={90:$z_{\pgfmathresult}$}] (h-\x) at (3,{-\x-div(\x,4)+.5}) {};
            }
            {
                \node[cnode=gray,label=90:$1$] (h-0) at (3,0.5) {};
            }
            \begin{scope}[on background layer]
              \draw (h-\x) --  (s1);
            \draw (h-\x) -- (s2);
            \draw (h-\x) --  (sK);
            \end{scope}
        }

        \node at (3,-3.5) {$\vdots$};

        \node[cnode=gray,label=90:$z_{M}$] (h-q) at (3,-5.5) {};
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \draw (h-q) --  (s1);
        \draw (h-q) -- (s2);
        \draw (h-q) --  (sK);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `\pgfmathresult` gets overwritten, so you may want to use `\pgfmathsetmacro` instead to store the result of the computation in a macro. (I also got rid of `xifthen` because it is not needed for integer comparisons, for which you can use a simple `\ifnum`.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [
          every label/.style={inner sep=0pt, opacity=0.8, text opacity=1.0, fill=white},
          cnode/.style={draw=black,fill=#1,minimum width=3mm,circle},
        ]
        \node[cnode=red,label=0:{$\hat y_1$}] (s1) at (6,-1) {};
        \node[cnode=red,label=0:{$\hat y_2$}] (s2) at (6,-2) {};
        \node at (6,-3) {$\vdots$};
        \node[cnode=red,label=0:{$\hat y_K$}] (sK) at (6,-4) {};

        \foreach \x in {0,...,4}
        {   
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myindex}{\x<4 ? \x : "q-1"}
            \ifnum\x>0
                \node[cnode=gray,label={90:$z_{\myindex}$}] (h-\x) at (3,{-\x-div(\x,4)+.5}) {};
            \else
                 \node[cnode=gray,label=90:$1$] (h-0) at (3,0.5) {};
            \fi
            \begin{scope}[on background layer]
              \draw (h-\x) --  (s1);
            \draw (h-\x) -- (s2);
            \draw (h-\x) --  (sK);
            \end{scope}
        }

        \node at (3,-3.5) {$\vdots$};

        \node[cnode=gray,label=90:$z_{M}$] (h-q) at (3,-5.5) {};
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \draw (h-q) --  (s1);
        \draw (h-q) -- (s2);
        \draw (h-q) --  (sK);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! Why does `pgfmathresult` get overwritten?

Comment: @pwesterbaan Because it gets used in basically all mathematical functions.When you say `label=90:...` Ti*k*Z computes the cosine and the sine of 90, and you get to see the result of `sin(90)`.

Comment: That is maybe a long-term thing to fix in the core.  It's quite annoying and there are always people running into that.

Comment: @HenriMenke Personally I feel that, if you are really to start modifying the core functions, there are much more urgent issues. For me personally this would be the possibility to switch locally to a slower `fpu` mode which avoids the `dimension too large` errors. But of course I do know that this is a gigantic task.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat You're right, that's an important issue as well, that the fpu is incompatible with drawing code.  But the code for the fpu isn't so nice, so I haven't gotten around to looking at that yet.  Maybe after I hand in my thesis.

Answer (score 1):

An another approach which not solve your problem with `pgfmathparse`. With slightly different nodes' positioning calculation with `\pgfmathparse` for nodes positions is omitted. For positioning are used `chains`, `fit` and `positioning` libraries only:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,
                chains,
                fit}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 6mm and 30mm,
  start chain = going below,
every label/.style = {label distance=2pt, inner sep=0.5pt, 
                      fill=white, fill opacity=0.8, text opacity=1},
      cnode/.style = {minimum size=3mm, on chain,
                      append after command = {\pgfextra{% this is used for correct positioning of nodes
                            \node[circle, draw, fill=#1, inner sep=0pt,
                                  fit=(\tikzlastnode)] {};}
                                              }% end of append after command
                     }
                        ]
\node (s1) [cnode=red,label=0:$\hat{y}_1$]  {}; 
\node (s2) [cnode=red,label=0:$\hat{y}_2$]  {};
\node (s3) [inner ysep=0pt, on chain]       {$\vdots$};
\node (s4) [cnode=red,label=0:$\hat{y}_K$]  {}; 
%
\node (h1) [cnode=green,label=$1$,                  
      above left = of  s1]    {};
\foreach \i in {1,2,4}
{
\scoped[on background layer]
\draw (h1) -- (s\i);
}
\foreach \i [count=\ii from 2] in {2,3,4,q-1,M}
{
\ifnum\ii=4 
    \node (h\ii) [inner ysep=0pt,on chain]   {$\vdots$};
\else
    \node (h\ii) [cnode=green,label=$z_{\i}$]    {};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \draw (h\ii) -- (s1);
    \draw (h\ii) -- (s2);
    \draw (h\ii) -- (s4);
            \end{scope}
\fi
}
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @cfr, thank you very much!