# Printing an element of a non-numeric array as the node label

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

I want to retrieve a member of a non-numeric array passed to a TikZ pic as an argument, to use it as a node label.  `\foreach` easily does it while iterating over the array, but I cannot do it for the individual elements.  The following are my two attempts that fail miserably:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
   pics/mypic/.style n args={1}{
      code={
         \foreach \a [count=\i] in {#1}{
            \node at (\i, 1) {$\a$};
         }

         % Attempt 1: Doesn't work
         % \node at (1, 2) {$#1[0]$};

         % Attempt 2: Doesn't compile
         % Error: Undefined control sequence. ... Missing $ inserted. ...
         \node at (2, 2) {$\pgfmathparse{{#1}[0]}\pgfmathresult$};
      }
   }
}

\tikz{\pic {mypic={\mathtt{a},\mathtt{b},\mathtt{c}};}}
% \tikz{\pic {mypic={a,b,c};}}   % It's the same for this one.
% \tikz{\pic {mypic={0,1,2};}}   % Attempt 2 works with this one,
% \tikz{\pic {mypic={0,a,2};}}   % but not with this one ("Unknown function `a').

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: bad array access]

I want to be able to somehow draw a node with the label `#1[0]`.  Regarding *Attempt 2*, I noticed that it yields the same errors also with the text arrays.  It works fine for the all-numeric arrays, but hybrid arrays are also troubling, even if the accessed element is numeric.

Comment: Try https://gist.github.com/moewew/2e0fcd582432a4ec72360f17085443d2. The non-numeric example entries in the array from p. 1030 are quoted with `"..."`, and that appears to be required to avoid blow-ups (see also p. 1026). There also appeared to be a scoping issue if `\pgfmathparse` is used too early/too far away from `\pgfmathresult`. I assume that `\pgfmathparse`/`\pgfmathresult` is also used internally, so you have to be careful that your use does not get overwritten.

Comment: Incidentally the answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134819/35864 also works here if you make sure that you use numbers where you need them: https://gist.github.com/moewew/52fd825cfdd491656ab3248eda6e6f66 (the important bit is accessing the array element via `evaluate=\x as \myvar using ({\radi[\x]})` and then `\myvar` that is unchanged).

Comment: Re `\pgfmathresult` being overwritten see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/497648/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9988/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510584/35864

Comment: @moewe I don't like the "quotes" solution. Primarily because it requires me (and anybody else struggling at this point) to wrap their every single non-numeric array element with quotes, and they are (and might also be for anybody else) a lot at this point. It also convolutes the `\foreach` statement using the array. Finally, it's hard to accept that it cannot be done without the quotes, when un-quoted non-numeric elements can be captured/stored by the `\foreach`'s iteration variable just fine.

Comment: I may very well be wrong, but my reading of the Ti*k*Z manual is that non-numeric input in arrays is only supported if the string is wrapped in `"..."`. I suspect some things may work without quotes, but that would be accidental and not something you can in general rely on. But I no next to nothing about Ti*k*Z so take that with a grain of salt.

Comment: @moewe I just posted an answer that makes use of `\foreach`. I see that the *TikZ & PGF Manual* explicitly states some examples iterating over arrays with un-quoted text and math. I don't think that solution relies on accidents.

Comment: Ah, there seems to be a difference between the *lists* that `\foreach` iterates over and the *arrays* that are evaluated with `\pgfmathparse` etc. The former may contain more or less arbitrary content but cannot be accessed via `[i]`. The latter may only contain stuff that is valid in the sense of §95.2 of the manual, but elements can be accessed with`[i]`. Apart from additional curly braces the two look the same for one-dimensional numerical values, but for non-numeric values arrays need `"..."`.

Comment: Your question and the answers here use the *list* convention of `\foreach`, but the question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134819/35864 uses *arrays* (and your title mentions arrays).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I use `listofitems` to read the desired data into an array `\mydata`.  The OP suggested a useful EDIT to my original approach by including all of the `listofitems` processing inside the `\tikzset` code.

Note that the `2` in `\mydata[2]`, calling out a single array element, can be any expandable calculation that results in an integer.  Also, negative values denote "reverse index", that is, relative to the end of the array, rather than the beginning.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{listofitems}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
   pics/mypic/.style n args={1}{
      code={
         \foreach \a [count=\i] in {#1}{
            \node at (\i, 1) {$\a$};
         }

         \readlist\mydata{#1}
         \node at (2, 2) {$\mydata[2]$};
      }
   }
}

\tikz{\pic {mypic={\mathtt{a},\mathtt{b},\mathtt{c}};}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think it does fit! However, I don't like the idea of having to make the `\readlist` call each time before drawing `mypic`. How about making that call in the pic's code instead? That way, we also get to also keep our document just as it was.

Comment: @UtkanGezer Thank you for your helpful edit.

Comment: Two valid answers within the same hour, and to a question 22 days old! I picked this one as *the* answer, as I will not be *maintaining* my hacky command in the other one, but the package `listofitems` sure might be.

Answer (score 2):

The following command uses `\foreach` to retrieve the element at a given index, and assign it globally to the given macro.

```
% Does #1 = #2[#3] with 0-based indexing
\newcommand\arrayget[3]{
    \foreach \a [count=\i from 0] in {#2}{
        \ifnum #3=\i
            \xdef#1{\unexpanded\expandafter{\a}}
        \fi
    }
}
```

References for the curious:

- Global definition with `\xdef`: [source 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353139/69346)
- `\unexpanded\expandafter{...}` to expand `\a` once: [source 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116835/69346)

It should be able to handle anything that `\foreach` can.  Demonstration:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\newcommand\arrayget[3]{   % Does #1 = #2[#3] with 0-based indexing
    \foreach \a [count=\i from 0] in {#2}{
        \ifnum #3=\i
            \xdef#1{\unexpanded\expandafter{\a}}
        \fi
    }
}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
   pics/mypic/.style n args={1}{
      code={
         \foreach \a [count=\i] in {#1}{ \node at (\i, 1) {$\a$}; }

         \arrayget{\asd}{#1}{0} \node at (1.5, 2) {$\asd$};
         \arrayget{\asd}{#1}{1} \node at (2.0, 2) {$\asd$};
         \arrayget{\qwe}{#1}{2} \node at (2.5, 2) {$\qwe$};
      }
   }
}

\tikz{\pic {mypic={\mathtt{a},\mathtt{b},\mathtt{c}};}}
\tikz{\pic {mypic={a,b,c};}}
\tikz{\pic {mypic={0,1,2};}}
\tikz{\pic {mypic={0,a,2};}}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Properly indexed]